# Store record inside parent array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have column date_added which has this format date 2017-02-09 08:45:48. I want to store all records of same month inside that specific month, like Feb month records should be inside Feb array. I'm trying following code.

```
$Res = array();
        $query   = $this->pdoConnection->prepare("select id,date from `record` ");
        $query->execute();
        header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
        $month = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $Data = $row;
            $array_date = date("m", strtotime($row['date']));
            $alpha_month = date("M", strtotime($row['date']));
            if(in_array($array_date,$month)){
                $Res[] = array($alpha_month=>array($Data));
            }
        }

        $output = array(
            'response' => $Res
        );  

        echo json_encode($output,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

**Result**

```
{
    "response": [
        {
            "Jan": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "date_added": "2017-01-03 08:43:09"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Feb": [
                {
                    "id": "4",
                    "date_added": "2017-02-04 10:53:44"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Feb": [
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "date_added": "2017-02-12 08:59:15"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see my code is return separate array of Feb, but i wanted to store both of inside Feb array. I have tried different logic but still facing same issue.

Comment: Instead `$Res[] = array($alpha_month=>array($Data));` you could do `$Res[$alpha_month][] = $Data;`

Comment: @Tyralcori You provide me very quick solution and guide +1. But due to less point i can't vote up your comment

Comment: i explained everything a little bit more detailed in my "answer". I am glad that i can help. If you need more information - feel free anytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit more detailed to my short comment above:

> Instead $Res[] = array($alpha_month=>array($Data)); you could do $Res[$alpha_month][] = $Data;

Currently you're fetching all result tuples in this while loop which is accurate and okay. But if you want to "group" some results in an array, one way to go with is:

```
$Res[$alpha_month][] = $Data;
```

With this code you're "pushing" the result ($Data) in your $Res array. The important part is the first array layer `$Res[$alpha_month]` which relates to the new structure:

```
array('JAN', 'FEB', ...);
```

The second `[]` declares for the first layer, in this case it's your month group, another array. You may will get `PHP WARNINGS` by pushing your result for every month in the first time, because `$Res[$alpha_month][]` leads to a two-level declaration inside your array.

In the first declaration, as mentioned earlier, you're pushing all groups / months into the array! But in the same time, php expects the first iterative, to be an array as well: (`$Res[$alpha_month][]`)

So the clean solution would be the following:

```
if(!isset($Res[$alpha_month])){
    $Res[$alpha_month] = array(); // You can also use []; instead array();
}
$Res[$alpha_month][] = $Data;
```

With that snippet, you're first checking the `$Res[$alpha_month]` for existence - which also declares an array, if the current layer is not available.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$Res[$alpha_month][] = $data;
```

That will just add an entry to your array for that month, you also don't need the `if(in_array($array_date,$month))` anymore